# Why did the UK agree to Spain's NATO membership seemingly without any Spanish concessions regarding Gibraltar?

Tags: united-kingdom, nato, spain, gibraltar

It seems fairly clear (or at least plausible) what Spain was hoping [to gain](http://www.cvce.eu/obj/the_accession_of_spain_to_nato-en-831ba342-0a7c-4ead-b35f-80fd52b01de9.html) by NATO membership, which was consummated as a rather later affair in the closing decade of the Cold War:

> The main reasons why the Government of Spain sought membership of the Atlantic Alliance were
> geopolitical, however. Given its military vulnerability, Spain, a country on the Iberian Peninsula, wanted to
> join NATO so as to guarantee its territorial integrity and thereby reinforce the security of the Balearic–
> Gibraltar Strait–Canary Islands axis by protecting it from possible foreign expansionism, principally from
> Morocco, which, having annexed Ifni and Western Sahara, now had ambitions to conquer the two Spanish
> cities in North Africa: Ceuta and Melilla. The Spanish Government furthermore feared potential offensive
> posturing by two other North African countries, Algeria and Libya, which were in the Soviet orbit. The
> Government also stated that Spain’s entry into NATO would merely ratify de jure a situation that already
> existed de facto under its agreements with the United States, namely the fact that Spain belonged to the
> Western defence system. Spain was also convinced that joining NATO would break the deadlock in
> negotiations for entry into the European Economic Community.

The [Socialist] Spanish government even put out a pamphlet that they were not giving up on the the goal of recovering Gibraltar by joining NATO. Despite these apparently convincing points, the Spanish population wasn't incredibly sold on the matter, with the NATO membership referendum in Spain passing with (just) 52.5% in favor.

It's not unheard of for countries to oppose NATO membership of those with whom they have some territorial dispute[s] with. So, I'm curious why did the UK agree to Spain's NATO membership seemingly without any concession from Spain on the matter of Gibraltar. Were there e.g. any discussions in UK's Parliament on the matter of getting some concessions from Spain regarding Gibraltar in relation to Spain's NATO accession? Were there overriding considerations?

Comment: What concessions does the UK need from Spain with regard to Gibraltar?  There was zero chance of Spain taking it by force before their acceptance into NATO, and even less afterward, theres no change in the UK stance on Gibraltar one way or the other, and the people of Gibraltar don't want to become Spanish (long been settled).  So what concessions did the UK need?  Spain to stop with its claims?  Wouldn't that be seen as overbearing by the UK when they can just continue to ignore Spain on the matter?

Comment: @Moo: because the continued Spanish claim, even if just "on paper", has made various UK foreign affairs matters more difficult e.g. the whole Spanish "veto" over Gibraltar in Brexit talks, to pick [a recent example](https://www.politico.eu/article/european-commission-releases-draft-mandate-for-post-brexit-gibraltar-talks/). N.B. Spain had already lifted its land embargo [in 1982](https://www.nytimes.com/1982/12/15/world/spain-ends-13-year-gibraltar-blockade.html), so in a sense they had made a concession.

Comment: The supposed veto in Brexit didnt really amount to much, did it?

Comment: I don't know where you have got your quote from, but I seriously doubt fears of aggresion by Morocco or any other north-african country played any part in Spain decission to join NATO. Spain could be weak, militarly speacking, yet an order of magnitude stronger than any of those possible foes. Joining NATO was a movement towards western recognition and integration in the greater world after 40 years of isolation of the francoist regime. Spain was looking for its place under the sun.

Comment: @Rekesoft It may have played a part. Geography has its importance, Ceuta and Melilla are very difficult to defend and Morocco could grab them, and the only option for Spain would be an seaborne invasion, which is a very complicated affair. Also at the time Spain was very politically unstable and just a few years ago Spain had lost Western Sahara to Morocco without a shot being fired.

Comment: @SJuan76: it's more or less how the [Ifni War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifni_War) happened.

Comment: @SJuan76 Spain lost Western Sahara to Morocco due to a political decision. As you say, no single shot was fired. Spain had the means to defend Western Sahara, or at least to make the Marcha Verde a bloodbath (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_March), but it chose not to: they disdained the local population rights, were even more opposed to communist-leaning Polisario Front than to Moroccan aspirations and were afraid of an unpopular war giving thrust to pro-democracy unrest in mainland Spain. Neither of these preconditions apply to 1982 socialist Spain.

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine that Spanish concessions on Gibraltar would have been of significant strategic value to the UK compared to Spanish membership in NATO. Starting a fight over the former would have jeopardized the latter.

Answer (score 3):

What concessions does the UK need from Spain with regard to Gibraltar? There was zero chance of Spain taking it by force before their acceptance into NATO, and even less afterwards, theres no change in the UK stance on Gibraltar one way or the other, and the people of Gibraltar don't want to become Spanish (long been settled). So what concessions did the UK need? Spain to stop with its claims? Wouldn't that be seen as overbearing by the UK when they can just continue to ignore Spain on the matter? @Moo

I seriously doubt fears of aggression by Morocco or any other North-African country played any part in Spain decision to join NATO. Spain could be weak, militarily speaking, yet an order of magnitude stronger than any of those possible foes. Joining NATO was a movement towards western recognition and integration in the greater world after 40 years of isolation under the Francoist regime. Spain was looking for its place under the sun. @Rekesoft

Comment: converting comments to CW

Comment: [The people of Crimea don't want to be Ukrainian](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/42011/34388) and the Palestinians do not want to be under a Jewish State, but the wishes of the people are disregarded in these cases.

Comment: Did you post that comment on the wrong question?  This one is about Spain's membership of NATO.

Comment: And if you think the Crimean people are "disregarded" by Russia...  where have you been in the last seven years!  If you think the Palestinian people are disregarded by the Arab world where have you been for the last 70!!

Comment: But both are disregarded by the UK, I don't know about Spain. I don't know how it is relevant what the people think.